# Issue running a child process from an electron app using spawn method

Tags: node.js, electron, child-process, electron-builder, electron-packager

I am trying to figure out a way to run a node child process in a packaged electron app using electron-packager. My requirement is to run this app on a machine with no node installed, so I should refer the node bundled with the electron app to run the child process. I packaged the app and executed it on a machine with no node installed and I faced certain issues, I tried to recreate the same issue by using a non packaged app on a machine with node installed, so now I realize this is not an issue with no node installation.

I am using spawn method with env variable ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE set, with process.execPath as command, but I am facing this below issue.

Note: I am facing this error even on a non packaged app run on a machine with node installed. The same code works perfectly fine with exec method with 'node' command in place of 'process.execPath' on the same machine.

```
    stdout: /Users/UserName/Desktop/proj/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js:57
throw e;
^Error: 
dlopen(/Users/UserName/Desktop/proj
/name/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/
src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node, 
1): Symbol not found: _GENERAL_NAME_free
Referenced from: 
/Users/UserName/Desktop/proj/
name/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc
/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node
 Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/UserName/Desktop/proj/name/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node
at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:172:20)
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:671:18)
at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:172:20)
at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:504:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:496:3)
at Module.require (module.js:586:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/UserName/Desktop/proj/name/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js:32:13)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/UserName/Desktop/proj/name/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js:63:3)
```

Please find my code below:

```
'use strict'

const fixPath = require('fix-path');
let functionName = () => {
    fixPath();           
    const child = childProcess.spawn(process.execPath, [path, 
    ....args], {
      // stdio: 'ignore',
      env: {
          ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE: 1
      }
});

child.on('error', (err) => {

});

child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' +data);
});

child.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
    console.log(code);
    console.log(signal);
});

child.unref();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use spawn to spawn a child process and use electron env variable.

```
child_process = spawn(command,args,{env: {"ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE":"1"}});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please check the updated question.